# How To get the comment count and put in blog page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I got a problem with my blog site http://unlieusurterre.fix-it-buddy-clients.com/blog/ if you hover the featured image post it shows the title,post like count and comment like count but the problem is I cant show the comment count of my blog posts :-( and this is the code of my blog posts any help are apreciated thank you. :-)

```
<div  id="blog-item" class="span3 post blogitem">
          <div class="img"> 
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( ) ?>">
         <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "ad_post_video", true) ) {
          echo '<div class="video2">';
          echo stripslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, "ad_post_video", true));
          echo '</div>';} else { ?>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
          the_post_thumbnail('Blog Pic');

      } else echo '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() 
       .'/img/no-img.jpg"
   alt="Placeholder" />'; ?>
   <?php }; ?></a> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" 
       class="mask"></a></div>

  <div class="text">
  <h6><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
             <?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
              <?php// custom_excerpt('regular') ?>
              <?php if(function_exists('like_counter_p')) 
            { like_counter_p('text for like'); }?>
    <span style="color:white;"><i class="icon-comment"></i>
           <?php  echo $comments_count->approved ?>comments</span>

     <div class="author-byline"> <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
              <h7><?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?></h7>
              <div class="pull-right"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                <?php the_time('F jS') ?>
              </div>
            </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: This is *painful* to read... Any chance you could clean it up a bit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

The Wordpress Codex is very helpful and worth a visit.

```
<?php comments_number( 'text to show for zero comments', 'text to show for one
comment', 'text to show for more comments' ); ?>
```

Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

**Update**: Above function has to be called within The Loop.

Outside The Loop you can use:

```
<?php $thepost = $post->ID;
      $comment_count = $thepost->comment_count;
      echo $comment_count;
?>
```

Comment: I get concept i think its only work within the post page what i need is i get the comment count of one post to show it in my blog page http://unlieusurterre.fix-it-buddy-clients.com/blog/

Comment: Yep, it has to be called within The Loop. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my problem :-) just get the comments number and it works width my site thanks for your help guys

```
      <?php wp_count_comments( post_id ); ?> 

        <span style="color:white;"><i class="icon-comment"></i>
      <?php  echo $comments_count->approved ?>
        <?php  echo $my_var ?>
     comment/s</span>
```